# How do I unserialize a decompressed R object

Tags: r

I want to take an R object, in particular an Eventlog, serialize it, compress it and write it to file. I then want to be able to read it into R decompress it and unserialize it.

I think I am doing the serializing and compression fine, but when I try to read it back into R I run into issues. In particular, I fail to unserialize it. The below is my best effort

```
library(eventdataR)
data("patients")

# Serialize eventlog selecting ascii as true to avoid nul errors
serialized_eventlog <- rawToChar(serialize(object = patients, connection =  NULL, ascii = TRUE))

# Create a connection object with gzip compression - wb write binary
compressed_con <- gzcon(file("event_log.RDS.gz", "wb"))

# Write the serialized object to the compressed connection
writeBin(serialized_eventlog, compressed_con)

# Close the compressed connection
close(compressed_con)

# Create a connection object with gzip decompression
decompressed_con <- gzcon(file("event_log.RDS.gz", "rb"))

# Read the decompressed serialized object from the connection
decompressed_serialized_eventlog <- readBin(decompressed_con, raw(), n = file.info("event_log.RDS.gz")$size)

# Close the decompression connection
close(decompressed_con)

# Create a raw connection with the decompressed serialized object
raw_con <- rawConnection(decompressed_serialized_eventlog)

# Load the unserialized object into R
deserialized_eventlog <- unserialize(charToRaw(as.character(raw_con)))
```

The error I get with the above is

```
Error in unserialize(charToRaw(as.character(raw_con))) : read error
```

I have tried this alternative line also, but it does not work

```
decompressed_serialized_eventlog <- readBin(decompressed_con, character(), n = file.info("event_log.RDS.gz")$size)
```

My sessioninfo

```
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2019 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

time zone: Europe/Dublin
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] eventdataR_0.3.1  R.utils_2.12.2    R.oo_1.25.0       R.methodsS3_1.8.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0  tools_4.3.0     rstudioapi_0.14
```

If anyone could give me some help with this that would be great

Comment: You have some redundant / incorrect steps in your attempt - but is there any reason you are not using `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`?  These functions serialize, compress, and write the object (and the reverse) in one step.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My use case is actually saving the eventlog to a SQL Server database. I want to compress before saving just because of the size of the eventlogs. Above I was trying to workout the conversion part without the database element. I think I will just serialise to a string without compression and save that, as the compressed binary vector would have to be converted to a character to be saved in the database